# How to add date items to arrays dependent on each other and sort them after?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I currently have two arrays, the end result of an API call.

The array looks like this:

```
   {
      "data":[
         {
            "Total":[
               3173.18
            ],
            "currency":[
               "USD"
            ],
            "xaxis":[
               "Feb 2022"
            ]
         }
      ],
      "id":"TotalPerMonth"
   }
```

I want to add missing months to the `xaxis` array, which I already have in the form of another array that looks like this:

```
['Nov 2021', 'Dec 2021', 'Jan 2022', 'Feb 2022', 'Mar 2022', 'Apr 2022']
```

while the entire API return looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "data":[
         {
            "Item 1":[
               0
            ],
            "Item 2":[
               0
            ],
            "Item 3":[
               10.7
            ],
            "Item 4":[
               0
            ],
            "Item 5":[
               0
            ],
            "Item 6":[
               2890.53
            ],
            "Item 7":[
               90.01
            ],
            "Item 8":[
               0
            ],
            "Item 9":[
               0
            ],
            "Item 10":[
               0.56
            ],
            "Item 11":[
               0
            ],
            "Item 12":[
               181.38
            ],
            "currency":[
               "USD"
            ],
            "xaxis":[
               "Feb 2022"
            ],
            "~":[
               0
            ]
         }
      ],
      "id":"TotalServicePerMonth"
   },
   {
      "data":[
         {
            "Total":[
               3173.18
            ],
            "currency":[
               "USD"
            ],
            "xaxis":[
               "Feb 2022"
            ]
         }
      ],
      "id":"TotalPerMonth"
   }
]
```

The question is, how do I add the missing months to the `xaxis` array, add placeholder values to them on the `Total` array, and most importantly, sort them according to each other's respective values before I send the data off to ECharts?

An example output:

```
   {
      "data":[
         {
            "Total":[
               0,
               0,
               0,            
               3173.18,
               0,
               0,
            ],
            "currency":[
               "USD"
            ],
            "xaxis":[
               "Nov 2021",
               "Dec 2021",
               "Jan 2022",
               "Feb 2022",
               "Mar 2022",
               "Apr 2022"
            ]
         }
      ],
      "id":"TotalPerMonth"
   }
```

Comment: Can you show example output you want to?

Comment: Added an example output! @VMT

Answer (score 0):

something like that?

```
missingMonthsArray.forEach((i) => {
    array[position].data[0].xaxis.push(i)
})
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the reply! my apologies, could you explain further?